# Clickonce: Appropriate for web site that is only supported in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, clickonce

We are looking for an easy way for our users to download and install a small client widget (it is a windows app) used with our (much larger) web app.

Our web app is currently only supported in Chrome.

Our concern is that the clickonce support piece may be missing from most Chrome installs.

The questions:

-- Is clickonce really going to be useful in this situation?

-- What is the best option for "one click" download-and-install for Chrome on windows?

Comment: What is your "client widget"? What does it do for the site?

Comment: @duskwuff OP enhanced

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce uses NPAPI which is being removed from Chrome. You will need to look at NaCl, Native Messaging or PPAPI instead of ClickOnce. There used to be browser extensions that you could use, however they have been removed from the store (or no longer work).

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome should not matter, so yes Click once will be useful in this situation. 
The only thing you need to worry about is your clients using Windows and the appropriate version of the .net framework. I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought that clickonce only works in chrome if the .net helper for clickonce is installed in chrome?